# Object deep cloning without Java reflection

Tags: java

What are the possibilities of doing deep object cloning without Java reflection? I have used Object cloning libraries that use reflection but AppEngine does not allow to do that.

So my existing application that worked with Tomcat not does not work.

**Update:**

Dozer library seems to be the best bet:

```
Mapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
DestinationObject destObject =  mapper.map(sourceObject, DestinationObject.class);
```

Question would be if I don't need custom mapping can I just do the above as it is?

For example:

```
Cat cat = new Cat();

Mapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
Cat newCat =  mapper.map(cat, Cat.class);
```

**Update:**

When I run my app with Dozer I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.contains(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z
    at org.dozer.util.ResourceLoader.getResource(ResourceLoader.java:53)
    at org.dozer.util.DefaultClassLoader.loadResource(DefaultClassLoader.java:44)
    at org.dozer.config.GlobalSettings.loadGlobalSettings(GlobalSettings.java:116)
    at org.dozer.config.GlobalSettings.<init>(GlobalSettings.java:67)
    at org.dozer.config.GlobalSettings.<clinit>(GlobalSettings.java:46)
```

Looks like I am missing something, although I added Dozer using Maven.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html

Comment: I had once benchmark about this and `Clone was the fastest` `second was reflection` and `last one was serialization`. So I always use `clone` or `copy()`

Comment: @AmitD Even if I add Cloneable interface to the class, it still does not have clone() or copy()

Comment: Why not just write a proper copy function, like you probably ought to?

Comment: @xybrek You need to override clone() method from Object class or provide `copy constructors` you then don't need clone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/gettingstarted.html)?

[from their website]

> Dozer is a Java Bean to Java Bean mapper that recursively copies data
>   from one object to another. Typically, these Java Beans will be of
>   different complex types.
>
> Dozer supports simple property mapping, complex type mapping,
>   bi-directional mapping, implicit-explicit mapping, as well as
>   recursive mapping. This includes mapping collection attributes that
>   also need mapping at the element level.
>
> Dozer not only supports mapping between attribute names, but also
>   automatically converting between types. Most conversion scenarios are
>   supported out of the box, but Dozer also allows you to specify custom
>   conversions via XML.

Comment: Do you have an affiliation with Dozer?  Just curious.

Comment: @duffymo Not at all. I've just used that framework in a couple projects and it seems like it might fit with what xybrek is trying to do.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I like to ask when people recommend things.  Hidden biases are made plain.

Comment: @DomenicD. Your answer seems to fit the solution I need however I have few question since you've used it already, see my updated question. Cheers!

Comment: It looks like for some reason you are using either an outdated or really new version of commons-lang that doesn't support `contains(String,String)`. Make sure you're using version 2.5.

Comment: Well Dozer uses reflection, whereas original question was how to this without it.
To create a copy without reflection, I would suggest to use MapStruct, which is also bean mapping tool, but which works by generating code (annotation processor).
Here you can find cloning example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57378469/can-i-create-a-deepcopy-of-an-java-object-entity-with-mapstruct

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can always do a deep clone by hand, just override the `clone()` method in your class(es). Very repetitive work, but feasible. And more efficient than using reflection, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream. This uses reflection but your SecurityManager might allow it as you are not calling it directly.