# Can I create a DeepCopy of an Java Object/Entity with Mapstruct?

Tags: java, jpa, deep-copy, mapstruct

I have a JPA entity (but this question is interesting in general) that consists of multiple child classes (aggregation).

I need to create a new entry in the DB that is 90% identical to the existing one (a few business values and of course the IDs need to be different).

As we need mapstruct for mapping between entity and TO I was thinking "Can mapstruct do this for me?" After Creating a deep copy I could simply update the remaining fields and persist the object.

Writing a copy constructor by hand is error prone (as newly added fields could be forgotten), a generator aproach would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you can use `@DeepClone`:

This Javadoc contains an example:
https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/api/org/mapstruct/control/MappingControl.html

```
 @Mapper(mappingControl = DeepClone.class)
 public interface CloningMapper {

     CloningMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( CloningMapper.class );

     MyDTO clone(MyDTO in);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But be careful though. If MapStruct discovers the same type on source and target it will simply take (not clone) the source type. Unless you define a method signature for it.

In other words: check the generated code carefully.

Comment: Can you expand on this? What is the "source ripe"?

Comment: It's when you try to swipe 'type' on a mobile . I corrected the answer

Comment: Do you have an example for ths? Especially for the specific mapping that is needed. I want to avoid to write everything explicitly and was hoping for an automatism.

Comment: I can't provide an example atm (have no availability over a computer). As it stands, you'll need to provide a mapping method signature for each nested type in your object tree. There has been some demand for (automated) deep cloning in the past, so check out the issues

Comment: See https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/695 for supporting deep cloning